# Return JSON data from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So far here is my code:

```
foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data["id"] =  $price->id;
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```

I would like it to become something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"id": 1},
        {"id": 2},
        {"id": 3}
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `json_encode`?

Comment: `$data[]["id"] =  $price->id;`

Comment: If that comment helped then you should probably accept @ConalMittal answer

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data[]["id"] =  $price->id;
}
$result["data"] = $data;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use json_encode() to returns the JSON representation of a value

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Really this is just a comment

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
<br>
      $prices = ['data'=>['id'=> '1', 'orange'=>'2']];
foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data['data'] =  $price;
}

$result = $data;
echo json_encode($result)
?>
```

output

{"data": {"id": "1", "orange": "2"}}